# Spam filtering for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, spam-prevention

Has anybody come across an elegant and efficient .NET spam filtering component that can be used in ASP.NET applications? I want something that I can pass a string and returns to me a percentage of how likely it could be spam, does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 6):

Akismet is great.

This provides a .NET API to the Akismet service: http://www.codeplex.com/AkismetApi